# Need counts by day from two different dates in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, teradata

I feel like this should be an easy thing to do, but I am struggling with it.

I have a table of issues and I have the following in the table:

- User ID
- Created Date
- Resolved Date
- Issue Number

I two summarize this by User ID with the number of Issues Created on a date and the number of Issues Resolved on a date.,

For example,

```
User ID   ///   Date     ///     Issues Received  ///  Issues Resolved
JonSmith1 ///  1/12/2015 ///            28        ///          34
```

The issue arises from the fact that I don't care when the issues was received when I'm calculating resolved Issues. So Issues in the Resolved calculation could have been received yesterday, last week, last year, etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, 
PE

Comment: How issues received is lesser then issues resolved

Comment: for a given day, it can be. on the 12th, for example they may receive 28 total issues, but still have X number in their queue from previous days that they close on the 12th.

Answer (score 0):

Do separate queries for the two dates, and then combine them with `UNION`:

```
SELECT UserID, Date, MAX(IssuesReceived) AS IssuesReceived, MAX(IssuesResolved) AS IssuesResolved
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, CreatedDate AS Date, COUNT(*) AS IssuesReceived, 0 AS IssuesResolved
    FROM Issues
    GROUP BY UserID, Date
    UNION
    SELECT User, ResolvedDate AS Date, 0 AS IssuesReceived, COUNT(*) AS IssuesResolved
    FROM Issues
    GROUP BY UserID, Date) AS u
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select userid,createddate as date,
      count(`created date`) as `Issues Received`,
      count(`Resolved Date`) as `Issues Resolved`
from yourtable 
where `Resolved Date` = '1/12/2015'
Group by userid,createddate
```

Considering that resolved date will be null when a new issue is created

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this totally answers your question, but likely you will need to do a union like this:

```
select user_id
    , action_date
    , count(case when action = 'CREATED' then 1 else null end)
    , count(case when action = 'RESOLVED' then 1 else null end)
from (
     select user_id, created_date action_date, 'CREATED' action
     from table
     union
     select user_id, resolved_date, 'RESOLVED' action
     from table
     where resolved_date is not null
     ) x
group by user_id, action_date
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using Teradata, you can use `full outer join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.UserID, r.UserId) as UserId,
       COALESCE(i.Date, r.Date) as Date,
       COALESCE(IssuesReceived, 0) AS IssuesReceived, 
       COALESCE(IssuesResolved, 0) AS IssuesResolved
FROM (SELECT UserID, CreatedDate AS Date, COUNT(*) AS IssuesReceived
      FROM Issues
      GROUP BY UserID, Date
     ) i FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT User, ResolvedDate AS Date, COUNT(*) AS IssuesResolved
      FROM Issues
      GROUP BY UserID, Date
     ) r
     ON i.UserId = r.UserId and i.Date = r.Date;
```